# Finding prior art referenced in the description of an existing patent?

Tags: prior-art

In reference to the patent: [US6622464](https://www.google.com/patents/US6622464)

The description from this patent reads:

> The applicants have discovered that the placement of the prior art pivot axis 192 and the geometry of bedbar 186 relative to reel 22 causes the front edge of bedknife 24 to also move rearwardly relative to reel 22 as it moves upwardly... As this happens, the Applicants further discovered that the cutting reel would become more aggressive in its cutting action...

Is there a way for me to find what prior art was being referenced in this paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

The patent specification mentions a few US patents in the introduction (Background of Invention). Have you checked those already?